# YAML Parser multiple root files without key

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I know is possible to have multiple root in a yaml file, but is possible to have without a key, something like this?

```yaml
- operationId: "ssss"
  applicationName: "common"
  deniedConfigurations: {}
  deniedRoles: {}
  permission: "read"

- operationId: "ddd"
  applicationName: "common"
  deniedConfigurations: {}
  deniedRoles: {}
  permission: "read"
```

Because actually I can't figure it out and I cannot find on internet if is possible without a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you show is a YAML stream with a single root, which is a sequence. It is entirely valid YAML.

Multiple roots in a stream mean multiple documents:

```yaml
spam: egg
sausage: spam
---
- droggel
- jug
```

Here, we have two documents, the first one with a mapping as root, the second one with a sequence.